# How to hatch PolyCollection instance?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to hatch PolyCollection instance?
I want to hath a PolyCollection returned from fill_betweenx.

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = 1.2*np.sin(4*np.pi*x)

fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

PC = ax1.fill_betweenx(x, 0, y1)
# I want to do something like this
# PC.set_hatch('\')
# but there is no such method

show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = 1.2*np.sin(4*np.pi*x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pc = ax.fill_betweenx(x, 0, y1, color='blue')

# Now we'll add the hatches...
for path in pc.get_paths():
    patch = PathPatch(path, hatch='/', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(patch)

plt.show()
```

[image]