# how to fill pcolor with hatches by mapping it alongwith color fill

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, colormap

Hi I want to continue from what I already ask in here
[Create vertical stacked bar chart referenced to y values (lithology/stratigraphic column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295970/create-vertical-stacked-bar-chart-referenced-to-y-values-lithology-stratigraphi?noredirect=1#comment113924884_64295970)

The question is how to make multiple hatches on my pcolor, here is the picture

[image]

I want to make that white colored pcolor with 'x' pattern, and the red one with '+'.

Any ways to do it? thank you in advance

```
lithcode = {'ABT': 1, 'AT': 2, 'GD': 3, 'BAT': 4, 'BTT': 5, 'TT': 6, 'NC': 7, 'MV':8, 'MS':9, 'GW':10}
colors = ['darkred', 'crimson', 'red', 'peru', 'lightsalmon', 'lightpink', 'white', 'oldlace', 
          'thistle', 'lightgray']
hatch=['','+','','','','','x','','','']
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)


Zb=litho['litho'].map(lithcode).to_numpy().reshape(1, -1)
nonan=np.count_nonzero(Zb[np.logical_not(np.isnan(Zb))])
Za=litho['litho'][:nonan].map(lithcode).to_numpy().reshape(1, -1)
X=litho['elev litho'][:nonan]
cl.pcolor(X, [0, 1], Za, cmap=cmap, vmin=1, vmax=len(colors))

# ax.set_yticks(data['md litho']) optionally set the y-ticks to indicate the row borders
hands = [Patch(color=col, label=k) for k, col in zip(lithcode.keys(), colors)]
cl.legend(handles=hands, loc=(1.01, 0), ncol=2, fontsize=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the linked example data, and on [How to hatch PolyCollection instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640951/how-to-hatch-polycollection-instance) for a method to hatch the `PolyCollection` created by `pcolor`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.patches import Patch, PathPatch
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'md litho': [0, 31, 49, 67, 406, 427, 442],
                   'litho': ['NC', 'AT', 'BTT', 'NC', 'ABT', 'BAT', 'NC']})
lithcode = {'ABT': 1, 'AT': 2, 'GD': 3, 'BAT': 4, 'BTT': 5, 'TT': 6, 'NC': 7, 'MV': 8, 'MS': 9, 'GW': 10}
colors = ['darkred', 'crimson', 'red', 'peru', 'lightsalmon', 'lightpink', 'white', 'oldlace', 'thistle', 'lightgray']
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)
hatches = ['', '++', '', '', '', '', 'xx', '', '', '']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 1.4))
lithcode_values = df['litho'][:-1].map(lithcode).to_numpy()
polycollection = ax.pcolor(df['md litho'], [0, 1], lithcode_values.reshape(1, -1), cmap=cmap, vmin=1, vmax=len(colors))
ax.set_xticks(df['md litho'])  # optionally set the x-ticks to indicate the column borders
ax.set_yticks([])  # hide ticks on the y-axis

for path, d2_val in zip(polycollection.get_paths(), lithcode_values):
    hatch = hatches[d2_val - 1]
    if hatch != '':
        ax.add_patch(PathPatch(path, hatch=hatch, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black'))

hands = [Patch(facecolor=col, label=k, edgecolor='black', hatch=hatch) for k, col, hatch in
         zip(lithcode.keys(), colors, hatches)]
ax.legend(handles=hands, bbox_to_anchor=(1.03, 1.02), loc='upper left', ncol=2, fontsize=8, facecolor='PaleTurquoise')
plt.tight_layout()  # this fits the legend and the labels nicely into the figure
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Importing `matplotlib.pyplot` as `cl` is extremely confusing.

Comment: Hi sorry @JohanC, I was away from this python work for a while. I still have problem in the hatch for loop. When I used my own script, not from your example, there is an error message says that at ---> hatch = hatches[d2_val - 1] 'only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index'. I am still figuring it out actually

Comment: Could you print out `lithcode_values` and check that is an array of integers? That way `d2_val` in the code above should be a single integer. Could you edit your question with the code changes?

Comment: Heyy @JohanC, it is working! Thank you very much!